# Parse html page with mechanize to receive the appropriate array

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

I have the following html code on the page received by mechanize (agent.get):

```
<div class="b-resumehistorylist-views">

<!-- first date start-->

<div class="b-resumehistory-date">date1</div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time1</div>
<a href="company_lynk1">company1</a></div>


<!-- second date start -->

<div class="b-resumehistory-date">date2</div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time2</div>
<a href="company_lynk2">company2</a>
</div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time3</div>
<a href="company_lynk3">company3</a></div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time4</div>
<a href="company_lynk4">company4</a></div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time5</div>
<a href="company_lynk5">company5</a></div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time6</div>
<a href="company_lynk6">company6</a></div>

<div class="b-resumehistory-company">
<div class="b-resumehistory-time">time7</div>
<a href="company_lynk7">company7</a></div>

...

</div>
```

I need to search inside the div with class="b-resumehistorylist-views" each date.
Then find all divs between two div-dates and link each item to this particular date.

The problem is that each item (div class = b-resumehistorylist-views) is not inside div=b-resumehistorylist-views.

At final stage I need to receive the following array:
`array = [ [date1, time1, company1, companylink1], [date2, time2, company2, companylink2], [date2, time3, company3, companylink3],[date2, time4, company4, companylink4] ]`

I know that I must use method search with text() option, but I cannot find the solution.
My code right now can parse all companies information between div class=b-resumehistory-company, but I need to find right date.

Comment: My code: `mydata = page.search("//div[@class='b-resumehistory-company']").map {|n| n.text}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the same thing as before, just some of the class attributes have been changed:

```
doc = agent.get(someurl).parser
doc.css('.b-resumehistory-company').map{|x| [x.at('./preceding-sibling::div[@class="b-resumehistory-date"][1]').text , x.at('.b-resumehistory-time').text, x.at('a').text, x.at('a')[:href]]}
```